# Spring authentication randomly stops responding and blocks application access

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

We have the problem with our Web application that is based on Spring security authentication. It used to work fine while there was small number of test users. However, once we got live and number of users have been increased we started to experience weird problems with spring authentication. Since we are using load balancer and have application on multiple amazon. Application restart solves the problem only temporary. We turned on debug logging, but it doesn't indicate any specific problem.

Our spring security context.xml is here https://db.tt/148w2Pfh

Web.xml is https://db.tt/OqG3buPA

Spring authentication service https://db.tt/5v2rFNDW

Logs when trying to login using OpenID authentication  https://db.tt/tDOpnVO5

Logs when trying to login using Spring security authentication https://db.tt/JxiwTY8a

Threads stack https://db.tt/F3Xtbk9R

I hope somebody will got idea what might be the problem.

Thanks

Update:
Hibernate configuration

```
public PropertiesFactoryBean hibernateProperties() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    Properties properties = createHibernateProperties();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setProperties(properties);
    return propertiesFactoryBean;
}

private Properties createHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", false);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 0);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", validate);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 50);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", 200);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", true);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.autocommit", false);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache",true);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", true);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries", true);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
    return properties;
}

@Bean (destroyMethod = "close")
public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() {
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    try {
        dataSource.setDriverClass(Settings.getInstance().config.database.driver);
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(Settings.getInstance().config.database.url+"?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
        dataSource.setUser(Settings.getInstance().config.database.user);
        dataSource.setPassword(Settings.getInstance().config.database.password);

        dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(10);
        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(5);
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(5);
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(50);
        dataSource.setMaxStatements(50);
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(3000);
        dataSource.setAutomaticTestTable("testTable");

    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }

    return dataSource;
}
```

Hibernate context:

```
<!-- Adding exception translation to a template-less Hibernate DAO  -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory for the datasource -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>org.prosolo.domainmodel</value>
            <value>org.prosolo.services.logging.domain</value>
            <value>org.prosolo.services.tree.settings.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="namingStrategy">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Spring configuration related to the datasource:

```
<!-- TRANSACTION CONFIGURATION -->

    <!-- Allowing annotation-driven transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="taskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Error retry advice -->
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="transactional"
            expression="execution(* org.prosolo.services.general.impl.AbstractManagerImpl.saveEntity(..))" />
        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="transactional" advice-ref="retryAdvice"
            order="-1" />
    </aop:config>

    <bean id="retryAdvice"
        class="org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor" />
```

Comment: My guess, based on what you posted here, is wrong use of the `DataSource` or absent/improper transaction configuration. Leading to pool starvation.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is wrong with datasource  and what should I change?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong but judging by what you posted here yuor pool starves. What needs to change I have no idea because there is no code, configuration etc. If you are messing around with a datasource yourself or opening hibernate session/entitymanagers yourself I have one suggestion don't.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited original post to include my Hibernate settings. Could you please let me know if you came to that conclusion based on the threads stack or there is anything else indicating problems with database connection. I'm asking this because I don't have idea where should I investigate.

Comment: In addition, one more question. If there is a pool starvation, and I remove my instance from load balancer, so there is no application use, isn't that suppose that connections become available at some point again?

Comment: Please add some code instead of links to resources, if you want people to help you you shouldn't let them click links but provide an overview. Just dropping a hibernate xml file isn't going to do much. You are using Spring so I would expect a Spring configuration for hibernate, also some datasource/pool settings in that configuration. The hibernate pool isn't intended for production usage.

Comment: You're right. In my original post I didn't know what should I focus on, so that's why added configurations as external links. I added know Hibernate and Spring configuration details from my source. I hope this is enough to indicate where might be the problem.

Comment: Can you add the configuration for the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` as that is missing as well as the xml configuration for hibernate.

Comment: Also what is that settings object you are creating? Why not just use the Spring environment for that?

Comment: I'm sorry but I find your configuration confusing. XML that isn't XML, java and xml based mixing. Use of beans that aren't needed. Your web.xml mentions only configuration classes but you are posting XML. So I don't have a clue anymore what is the correct stuff or what isn't.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I shouldn't post that XML file. I have configuration of the whole application (database settings, hibernate settings, elasticsearch settings, application specific settings...) in one xml file. On the application start I'm parsing this to java using xml simpleframework and use it to configure hibernate. So please ignore that xml file I posted earlier. It's not important for hibernate configuration as the only place I'm configured hibernate are PropertiesFactoryBean.java and hibernate config.xml I posted above.

Comment: I think you pointed in good direction. Once instance got into the problems, I got this exceptions SqlExceptionHelper:147 - An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.lang.InterruptedException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that M.Deinum was right in his comment that there is connection pool starvation. My solution for this problem, was to replace c3p0 data source with Tomcat pool data source. After this change I didn't have the problem anymore. Updated version is given bellow.

```
    @Bean (destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource() {

    PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
    p.setUrl(Settings.getInstance().config.database.url+"?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
    p.setDriverClassName(Settings.getInstance().config.database.driver);
    p.setUsername(Settings.getInstance().config.database.user);
    p.setPassword(Settings.getInstance().config.database.password);
    p.setJmxEnabled(false);
    p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
    p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    p.setTestOnReturn(false);
    p.setValidationInterval(30000);
    p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
    p.setMaxActive(100);
    p.setInitialSize(10);
    p.setMaxWait(10000);
    p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
    p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
    p.setMinIdle(10);
    p.setLogAbandoned(true);
    p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    p.setJdbcInterceptors(
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"
            + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;"
            + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer");
         org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
         ds.setPoolProperties(p);
         return ds;
 }
```